# How to create menu in Word Press 4.2.2?

Tags: menus, admin-menu

How to create menu in Word Press 4.2.2? I have opened a dashboard and there are no so options visible. How to fix that? I want to make a menu for all pages I`ve created. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean ` there are no so options visible`? What are you seeing in admin panel?

Comment: Post the screenshot of your admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Menus in the Appearance->Menus area in the admin. Are you using a custom theme? If so, it might have menu support. Try switching to one of the default themes. If it still, doesn't appear, disable all plugins and try again.

Comment: There is no Appearance, if it was so easy... it seems that the are no administrator/developer rights of account. On Bitnami stack everything works extremely easy and OK. Thank you.